# Terminate program when press "q"

Tags: java

I'm trying to terminate a program when user input "q". How can i stop the last two line of codes to not execute when user input "q"?
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String expression = "";
    while (!expression.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        System.out.println("Type an expression written in Infix notation: ");
        expression = input.next();
        PostFixConverter convert = new PostFixConverter(expression);
        System.out.println("This expression writtien in Postfix notation is: \n" + convert.infixToPostfix());

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What about `expression = input.next(); if (expression.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) break;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `while` use `do-while` loop if you want to iterate the code continuously based on user input.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String expression = "";

            System.out.println("Type an expression written in Infix notation: ");
            expression = input.next();

            if(!expression.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
            {
                do{
                    PostFixConverter convert = new PostFixConverter(expression);
                    System.out.println("This expression writtien in Postfix notation is: \n" + convert.infixToPostfix());

                    System.out.println("Type an expression written in Infix notation: ");
                    expression = input.next();
                }while (!expression.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
            }   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to simply use an `if` statement to check the value:

```
           if(!expression.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
                PostFixConverter convert = new PostFixConverter(expression);
                System.out.println("This expression writtien in Postfix notation is: \n" + convert.infixToPostfix())
           }
           else{
                System.exit(1);
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just break from your loop when you see that the user entered a "q". Also check whether there is more input to come:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String expression = "";
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Type an expression written in Infix notation: ");
        expression = input.next();
        if (expression.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            break;
        }
        PostFixConverter convert = new PostFixConverter(expression);
        System.out.println("This expression writtien in Postfix notation is: \n" + convert.infixToPostfix());
    }
}
```

---

### Note

Some of the other suggestions duplicate code - they print the same statements inside an outside the loop. Code duplication is never a good idea - it makes your code hard to maintain. What if you need to change the message? Now you need to do it in two places.